# How to keep drop dumplings from soaking up all the liquid while holding to be served

Tags: chicken, dumplings, catering

My wife and I have been doing a little catering and want to make our chicken and dumplings but we are not for sure how to keep the dumplings from soaking up all the broth. We use Bisquick to make our dumplings and just drop them in to the chicken broth pot for them to cook. Making and serving them at home is alright as we can add more water of chicken broth to thin them out but I'm not for sure that would work in catering and holding temp before being served.. Is there a different type of dumpling we should look at? Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Fresh, hot, fluffy, herby dumplings are a delight. But after just a few minutes they always seem to become a stodgy dead weight. Maybe they are not the best choice for mass catering?

Comment: That is what we were thinking but thought we would see if anyone else had any luck